# How to set spacing/padding in tables only on one side of the cell?

Tags: tables, spacing

I have another problem and hope you can help.
I want to set a padding/spacing in my table, but only on the right side of the cells. When I set the `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}%`, the padding is also on both sides.

So, my question, is there any way to set the padding only on one side of the cells?

Here is an example for what I have now, and you can see, that the spacing from the name to the next cell is very small.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
{\huge Information} \hfill \today \\

\begin{figure}[h]
 \sffamily  
 \begin{minipage}[t]{13cm}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{4cm}p{2.5cm}p{4cm}}             
  \textbf{Personalnr.:}     &101                        &\textbf{Gesch.-St.:}   &1              \\
  \textbf{Nachname:}        &BrahamanenSiddhartha123    &\textbf{Kost.-St.: }   &900            \\
  \textbf{Vorname:}     &Chandrakanta Umashankar    &\textbf{Geschlecht:}   &männlich       \\
  \end{tabular}
 \end{minipage}
 \hfill
 \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
  \vspace{8pt}
  %\includegraphics[height=5cm]{personalbild.png}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered inserting `@{}` to the left of the first column specifier and to the right of the final column specifier?

Comment: @Mico, can you explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}@{}p{4cm}...}` etc.

Comment: What's the `minipage` for?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you, thats what I want.  
The 'minipage' is to place the image on the right sight (like a floating right), I thought it would be the best way for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `tabular` column has a space left and right to the real cell content -- the width of this is normally specified with `\tabcolsep`, which defaults to `6pt`. Together with the cell content those spacings form up the *full cell*.

It's possible to erase this space completely using the `@{}` specifier:

For example: (see the images too, please)

`\begin{tabular}{llll}` would have `8` `\tabcolsep` spaces (left and right of `l`)

[image]

`\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}@{}l@{}@{}l@{}@{}l@{}` would have no such spaces, it's tight. The `@{}` right to the specifier `l` belongs to that one, not to next specifier!

[image]

However `@{}` can be used to set another skip, say `@{\hskip5pt}` for another spacing.

If vertical lines come into action, the width of the table is increased by `\arrayrulewidth` for each vertical line. (I've omitted the lines in the images above -- the shown borders are just for better impression and should not represent the potential vertical lines of the table)

I've done this and explicitly introduced vertical lines, just to show the effect, not for a real run!

In addition, I removed the `minipage` and added `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (for the cell vertical spacing `\usepackage{cellspace}` might be usefull, but I omitted it)

Any further comments on the design of the table → O.P!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
{\huge Information} \hfill \today \\

\begin{figure}[h]
 \sffamily  
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
%  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
   \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{4cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{4cm}|}             
  \textbf{Personalnr.:}     &101                        &\textbf{Gesch.-St.:}   &1              \\
  \textbf{Nachname:}        &BrahamanenSiddhartha123    &\textbf{Kost.-St.: }   &900            \\
  \textbf{Vorname:}     &Chandrakanta Umashankar    &\textbf{Geschlecht:}   &männlich       \\
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}@{\hskip5pt}|p{4cm}@{\hskip5pt}|p{2.5cm}@{\hskip5pt}|p{4cm}@{\hskip5pt}|}             
  \textbf{Personalnr.:}     &101                        &\textbf{Gesch.-St.:}   &1              \\
  \textbf{Nachname:}        &BrahamanenSiddhartha123    &\textbf{Kost.-St.: }   &900            \\
  \textbf{Vorname:}     &Chandrakanta Umashankar    &\textbf{Geschlecht:}   &männlich       \\
  \end{tabular}
 \hfill
  \vspace{8pt}
  %\includegraphics[height=5cm]{personalbild.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Now I understand it much more! :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you set `\tabcolsep` to `3pt` (default: `6pt`) and force LaTeX not to insert whitespace to the left of the first column or to the right of the final column by setting up the `tabular` environment as follows:

```
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{p{2.5cm}p{4cm}} @{}}
```

The `@{}` particles do the job of suppressing whitespace in the corresponding locations.

Incidentally, I would also dispense with the `minipage` environments inside the `figure` environment and replace the `figure` environment with a `minipage` of witdth `\textwidth`.

The output of the reworked example looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, hmargin=20mm, vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit "demo" option in real document
\begin{document}
{\huge Information} \hfill \today 

\bigskip
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \sffamily  
 %\begin{minipage}[t]{13cm}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}  % default value: 6pt
  \begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{p{2.5cm}p{4cm}} @{}}             
  \textbf{Personalnr.:} &101 &\textbf{Gesch.-St.:} &1              \\
  \textbf{Nachname:}    &BrahamanenSiddhartha123    &\textbf{Kost.-St.: }   &900            \\
  \textbf{Vorname:}     &Chandrakanta Umashankar    &\textbf{Geschlecht:}   &männlich       \\
  \end{tabular}
 %%\end{minipage}
 %%\hfill

 %%\begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}
  \vspace{8pt}
  \includegraphics[height=5cm]{personalbild.png}
 %%\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also a thank you to you, @Mico, it helps me to understand it much more.